# Sys.Date() origin

Tags: r, date

I'm struggling to understand the Sys.Date () function in R. When I type Sys.Date () into the consol it returns today's date, which is perfect. However, when I put it into a numerical matrix it returns 16001, which, when converted back to a date using `as.Date(16001,origin = "1900-01-01")` gives me 1943-10-24.

It it simply the case that the origin for Sys.Date () is 1970-01-01? Is it that simple?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: 1970-01-01 is the origin of UNIX time as a convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `origin="1900-01-01"` to `origin="1970-01-01"`. From the documentation of `?Sys.Date()` you can read:

> Sys.time returns an object of class "POSIXct"

And when reading `?POSIXct` you'll find:

> Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of 1970....

That's why you should set `origin="1970-01-01"` to recover today's date.